# Castle Active Record: SQL Express doesn't work. SQL Developer does

Tags: c#, sql-server-express, castle-activerecord

I've been trying to troubleshoot a Castle ActiveRecord exception for days now. Whenever I attempt to access the database I get an exception with an InnerException value of `"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file database.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."`

I'm trying to connect to an SQL Server Express 2005 database. I don't have any other database option because the school computers only have SQL Express on them.

My connection settings

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class
  NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver

hibernate.dialect

  NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect
hibernate.connection.provider
  NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider

hibernate.connection.connection_string
  Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=database.mdf
```

This fails to work even if I set AttachDBFilename to an absolute path. User Instance has no effect. The database file is currently in the root of the project mixed in with my WinForms classes.

When using

```
hibernate.connection.connection_string
  Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=FinalApp;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False
```

I have no problems doing this on my laptop but I can't use the SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition on the school computers.

Full Stack Trace as requested

```
Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordException was unhandled
  Message="Could not perform FindAll for Book"
  Source="Castle.ActiveRecord"
  StackTrace:
       at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.FindAll(Type targetType, Order[] orders, ICriterion[] criteria) in c:\dev\castle\svn\branches\1.0.x\ActiveRecord\Castle.ActiveRecord\Framework\ActiveRecordBase.cs:line 1022
       at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.FindAll(Type targetType) in c:\dev\castle\svn\branches\1.0.x\ActiveRecord\Castle.ActiveRecord\Framework\ActiveRecordBase.cs:line 982
       at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase`1.FindAll() in c:\dev\castle\svn\branches\1.0.x\ActiveRecord\Castle.ActiveRecord\Framework\ActiveRecordBase.Generic.cs:line 333
       at CSharpFinal.InventoryMain.InventoryMain_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\CSharpFinal\InventoryMain.cs:line 36
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
       at CSharpFinal.Form1.inventoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\CSharpFinal\Form1.cs:line 51
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at CSharpFinal.Program.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\CSharpFinal\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()


Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordException was unhandled
  Message="Could not create the schema"
  Source="Castle.ActiveRecord"
  StackTrace:
       at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchema() in c:\dev\castle\svn\branches\1.0.x\ActiveRecord\Castle.ActiveRecord\Framework\ActiveRecordStarter.cs:line 212
       at CSharpFinal.Form1.reInitializeDatabaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\CSharpFinal\Form1.cs:line 65
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at CSharpFinal.Program.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\CSharpFinal\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

`InnerException.Message` is `"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file database.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."`

Comment: please post the full stack trace

Comment: Two full stack traces causing the same inner exception error posted. I don't think they really help.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably becuase your SQL Express connection string is turning off user instance.  If you leave user instance turned on then SQL will attach the database if required, if not it will just open it.  If you turn it off then the attach is permenant.  Any attempt to use the same connection string again will result in an error because the database already exists.
Becuase you have not attached the database by using that connection string, you will need to detach the database before you can then use the correct connection string.
I suggest you download SQL management studio express, if you haven't already got it.  That will let you see the database already attached and detach it easily.

Okay, if that is not the problem can SQL server access the database file?  Has it got permissions on that folder?  It normally runs as network service, which you can grant access to the file just like any other user.  You could eliminate the file permissions as an issue by granting full control to everyone, if that fixes it then you can tweak the permissions down to what is required.  I would guess that the SQL server service account will require modify rights on the .mdf file.  I don't know where it creates the .ldf for a user instance database.  It might need create file rights in the same folder as the .mdf.

Comment: That didn't make any difference. Same exception. Same stack trace. Even with an absolute path to the database file.

Comment: It is already attached.  you will need to log in to the server first and un-attached the existing database.  Then remove set user instance to true.

Comment: The database is not attached in Management Studio. User instance still does not work. I have tried rebooting and it still does not work.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer with another alternative.  I assume the .mdf is on a local drive?  Is it in Program files or your my docs or where?

Comment: Which is in your my docs?  Have you tried granting the SQL service account permission to access the file? (The second paragraph in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, this is sort of a guess, but do you need to specify a database name?
(Initial Catalog in conn string)